# Browser detection with Leaflet library

Tags: javascript, browser, leaflet

How to detect the browser using the [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) library for JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the boolean method `L.Browser` for browser detection.

For example:

```
if ( L.Browser.ie ) {
    alert( "Using Internet Explorer" );
    // ...
}
```

This method supports the properties:

- **ie** - true for all Internet Explorer versions;
- **ie6** - true for Internet Explorer 6;
- **ie7** - true for Internet Explorer 7;
- **ielt9** - true for Internet Explorer versions less than 9;
- **edge** - true for Microsoft Edge;
- **webkit** - true for webkit-based browsers like Chrome and Safari (including mobile versions);
- **webkit3d** - true for webkit-based browsers that support CSS 3D transformations;
- **android** - true for Android mobile browser;
- **android23** - true for old Android stock browsers (2 and 3);
- **mobile** - true for modern mobile browsers (including iOS Safari and different Android browsers);
- **mobileWebkit** - true for mobile webkit-based browsers;
- **mobileOpera** - true for mobile Opera;
- **opera** - true for Opera;
- **touch** - true for all browsers on touch devices;
- **msTouch** - true for browsers with Microsoft touch model (e.g. IE10);
- **retina** - true for devices with Retina screens;
- **chrome** - true for Chrome.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#browser.

Comment: I am kind of surprised Leaflet has this in it's API (as shown in your self-answer). Browser detection is not always reliable and it might be better practice to do feature detection, or some other alternatives, instead of user agent detection:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent